# 'Object does not support property or method' error when counting rows

Tags: vba, excel

The following code produces the `Object does not support this property or method` error:

```
With CellsTab
    NumOfProdCells = .Range(.Cells(.Match(CurrentStartRow,.Range("MIRCellColumn"), 0), 4), 
    .Cells(.Match(CurrentStartRow,.Range("MIRCellColumn"), 0), 4).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count 
End With
```

`CellsTab` is a Worksheet, `NumOfProdCell`s is of type long, `CurrentStartRow` is also an integer, and `MIRCellColumn` is a named range in the worksheet `CellsTab`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is failing because of `.match`.
`.match` is a workbook function, but you are using it as if it is a method of the worksheet. Instead use:

```
With CellsTab
    NumOfProdCells = _
        .Range(.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CurrentStartRow, _
        .Range("MIRCellColumn"), 0), 4), _
        .Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CurrentStartRow, _
        .Range("MIRCellColumn"), 0), 4).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, this is giving me the error "Unable to get the Mach property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Comment: My apologies, it should be `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match()`. It also looks like you used `>4` in a `.Cells()` reference, which isn't valid. That may have just been a side effect of the formatting of the post, though.

Comment: It was indeed a formatting issue. Also, changing it to Application.Works... doesn't change or remove the error.

Comment: Is `.Range("MIRCellColumn")` contiguous? What is the value of `CurrentStartRow`?